# Is it appropriate to start an eV+ tag and ask questions about eV+ on SO

Tags: discussion

There is a coding language specific to Adept Robotics called eV+.

http://www1.adept.com/main/KE/DATA/V%20Plus/eVprelim/pdf/v_langug.pdf

Since it is a form of programing (although specific to a particular companies robots), is it appropriate to open a tag for this? It would obviously be rare for people to ask and answer questions on this site, but if i am asking and answering questions it might become useful in the future.

Comment: Are there any on-topic questions to tag with it? If not, this is futile. If yes, just go ahead.

Comment: There is a robotic site - http://robotics.stackexchange.com - but I'm not sure if the questions you have in mind would be on topic there. It doesn't have a [ev+] tag.

Comment: @MrLister the one that brought up this question was trying to loop over all the robots in v+ and get their gadget number .. It is more code than robotics i think.

Comment: @Deduplicator i was thinking about asking some.